# Work ON a farm, work IN a farm or work AT a farm? Which one is correct, why and the incorrect ones why not?

Tags: prepositions, nuance

As the title says. Please help me out with this :)

Comment: "On" is traditional (in the US) for most contexts.

Comment: See also: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+on+a+farm%2C+work+in+a+farm%2C+work+at+a+farm&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20on%20a%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20in%20a%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20at%20a%20farm%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. ***At*** a farm is correct in some contexts, for example if a plumber is fixing pipes in the house. This is not mentioned in the question suggested as a duplicate.